# Restoring Virtualbox machine images from old hard drive

Tags: virtualbox, restore, vdi

I recently replaced the HDD in my laptop, and re-installed Windows & Ubuntu.  Now I want to restore the various virtual machines I had set up on the old HDD, which is mounted in an external USB enclosure.  I can read the HDD okay, and the 'bad' spots seemed to be in the Windows partition...  but whenever I try to restore the VDI files the copy errors out.  I've tried drag-n-drop in Nautilus, I've tried grsync, etc.  Always bombs out on the VDI files.  I've copied over multi-GB dvd iso images with no problem, but the VDI files always fail the checksums.

Any ideas?

TIA,

Monte

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try a file recovery software like photorec.  As it seems that you are working with a damaged drive.

Another idea, did you try opening the vdi file directly from the old hdd?  I am not sure how that would help to be honest, but if that drive mounts and delivers data, you could check if the vdi file is corrupted, or whether this is a balky broken hdd that is just unwilling to give up the data.

Indeed, even if the file is quite corrupt, I would think you should be able to copy it anyway, even if you couldn't actually use it.

I am not expert, just trying to help :-)

Good luck.

Comment: Eventually I just went ahead and tried starting the VMs in Virtualbox.  Some worked, some gave an error, but worked fine once I discarded the current state and did the equivalent of a hard reboot (i.e. poweroff and restart).  Apparently what was getting corrupted was the file(s) that keep track of the 'state' of the VM... nothing too critical.

Comment: yeah all you need is the vdi file and you are ready to go, although you will need to reinstall guest additions perhaps.  the other files are not critical